# Performing merge of two very different branches complicated by need to fast-forward merge-commit

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-merge, git-rebase

I have a trouble. Had branches `master` and `feature`. One hundreds years ago `master` and `feature` had common ancestor, but 100500 commits passed since that times. `master` and `feature` branches are now VERY divergent. Ok. I have spent all day long and finally I have completed this %#$%# merge. But... At the end of the day I was going to do push this results to a repository and noticed that my teammates have made about 5 new commits in 'master' branch... $#%#$ It is important for us to do **rebase** to fast-forward my merge ahead this commits. So I need to incorporate this 5 commits in my merge results. I have already `E` commit (look at a scheme) on my local repo, which is a result of merging `master` into `feature`. I cannot push it on server because of C1, ... C5 - new commits on remote on `feature`. Standard practice for me when I have something new on remote, when I have already made changes, I do `git pull --rebase` to keep history of one branch linear. I ran `git pull --rebase` and got proposal from git in fact to do merge all again. There are a lot of conflicts again in files that were even untouched in C1,...C5 commits. What I'm doing wrong? Please help. How to get result, which I have drown on the second scheme? Am I crazy? Is it possible to do at all?

```
Now:

o--A--o-----...100500 commits....[master]....--o-----------B
       \                                                    \ 
        o---...100500 commits....[feature - local repo]...C--E(local repo - epic merge result)
        |                                    
        o---...100500 commits....[feature - remote repo]..C--C1--C2--C3--C4--C5(remote repo, feature branch - additional 5 commits)


Need to fast-forward E ahead C1, C2,... C5, that were added on remote when I was busy with merge:

o--A--o-----...100500 commits....[master]....--o-----------------------B
       \                                                                \ 
        o---...100500 commits....[feature]...--o--C--C1--C2--C3--C4--C5--E(epic merge result)
```

**Update**
When I'm doing `git pull --rebase` (staying on `feature` branch) I have noticed that git tries to put on top of C1,..,C5 (commits on remote of `feature` branch) first, then second, then other 100500 commits of `master` branch. It is not what I want. I need only `E` commit be on top of C1,..C5, but not all commits of `master` branch. I see this behavior, when I look into `gitk --all` between `git rebase --continue`, get conflict, `git mergetool` cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Take your history, with the merge, and rebase the 5 new commits on top of that. Yes, this isn't what you asked for, but be patient.

Resolve any merge conflicts that arise. This should be simple, since you're only dealing with the 5 new commits.

Now you have a resulting tree that's exactly what you want. Drop a tag here, and then throw away everything and start over.

Perform the merge anew, this time including the 5 new commits in the branch that you're merging in. But pass `-s ours` as a strategy option and `--no-commit` to avoid actually performing the commit.

Now read the tree from your previous merge+rebase. This should be as simple as `git checkout $tag -- .` (where `$tag` is the tag you placed on your previous result).

Now run `git commit`. This will commit your merge, with the history you want, and with the tree produced by your previous work.

If this looks good, go ahead and push it and delete your tag.

Comment: Sorry but I'm stupid, please explain your idea in more details. What does mean "Take your history, with the merge, and rebase the 5 new commits on top of that". Does it mean to process merge during rebase that I have aborted? (It is hell!)

Comment: @Dao: With your current history, you have master, with a merge of local feature. You want to rebase remote feature on top of that. Simplest way may actually just be a cherry-pick of all 5 commits (`git cherry-pick ..remote/feature`).

Comment: @Dao: Alternatively, you could check out your local feature branch, update it to match remote, and then just `git rebase master`.

Comment: hm.. I'm merging `master` -> into -> `feature`, but not `feature` into `master`. C1,..,C5 commits on remote are not on `master` but on remote `feature` branch. I don't need them on `master`. Are you sure with `git rebase master`? What I need to get from `master` branch? Everything is already in `E` commit. If you simply mismatched `master` with `feature`, please correct your comments. If I don't understand something, please explain. As I understand `git rebase master` tries to pull from remote\master and push my local new commits forward that has come from remote.

Comment: @Dao: Oh sorry, I was thinking the merge was in the other direction. Just change the branch you're working on. And actually, `git rebase master` does not, in fact, do what you think it does. It does no network activity whatsoever. That command will just rebase the current branch on top of `master`. The simplest thing for you may just be to `git checkout feature && git cherry-pick ..remote/feature` to grab those 5 commits. If you want to use `git rebase` you could do `git checkout feature && git reset --hard remote/feature && git rebase @{1}`. Cherry-pick is probably easier